# Connection denied while using mssh to connect to AWS Educate EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

AWS CLI is throwing this error. Am I doing something wrong or does my institution simply not allow me to connect? What's the point if this is valid? Frustrated.

CLI is throwing this error -

```
Error while pushing the public key:
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the SendSSHPublicKey operation: User: arn:aws:sts::550549147475:assumed-role/vocstartsoft/user1366934=ag618@g.harvard.edu is not authorized to perform: ec2-instance-connect:SendSSHPublicKey on resource: arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:550549147475:instance/i-0d13f5839e0d3dd00 with an explicit deny
```

Answer (score 1):

The operation you are trying to perform has been **explicit denied**. This means that AWS Educate prohibits such an action and you can't change that.

Please note, that AWS Educate Starter Accounts are **very limited**, and only a handful of services and operations are allowed:

- [AWS Services Supported with AWS Educate Starter Account](https://awseducate-starter-account-services.s3.amazonaws.com/AWS_Educate_Starter_Account_Services_Supported.pdf)